# Narrow helm-projectile-grep to specific file type

Tags: helm-projectile

I usually find myself when using helm-projectile-grep to narrow my search down to a specific file type.

For example: I do a search for "container" but only want to show the results in the .style files. I haven't been able to find if you can do this with helm-projectile-grep but it does seem like it should be possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with the [helm-ag](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-ag) package, which passes every "--" prefixed field to ag as CLI arguments.

To filter by file type use its extension as an argument. So calling *helm-projectil-ag* with:

```
--style container
```

will do the trick.

**Additional examples:**

```
--hidden search-pattern
```

Will include hidden files during search for *search-pattern*

```
--ignore=*.html container
```

Will ignore all html files. Note that *--ignore* accepts glob pattern instead of regexp.

**Requirement**

To use *helm-ag* you should install [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), which is multi-platform, uses perl-like regexp by default and is way faster than grep.

Comment: this doesnt work with helm-projectile-ag

Comment: @RichieHH yes, and I have never stated that.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike RichieHH stated in a comment under [atevm](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36442/24156)'s answer in 2020, it now do work with `helm-projectile-ag` too

For example, I managed to search for a string in all php files  with :

```
stringIsearchFor -G=*.php
```